Running Spark Jobs on All Shell Not Working (Could not reconfigure JMX, JavaSparkContext)
The title of the problem may not be appropriate. I will request all to go over the problem and if possible modify it accordingly which best describes it as I do not exactly know how to express it.
I am using bitnami/spark:3.4.2 and deploying it in podman (for Red Hat) similar to docker.
Dockerfile:
FROM bitnami/spark:3.4.2
ENV SPARK_HOME=/opt/bitnami/spark

Image build and container execution command:
podman build -t localhost/custom-bitnamispark-r-arrow .

podman run -d --name bitnami-spark-master \
       -p 8081:8080 -p 7077:7077 \
       -e SPARK_MODE=master \
       -v /home/podman/spark/extra-jars/:/opt/spark/extra-jars \
       -v /home/podman/spark/scripts/:/opt/spark/scripts \
       localhost/custom-bitnamispark-r-arrow:latest \
       /bin/bash -c "/opt/bitnami/spark/sbin/start-master.sh -h 0.0.0.0"

Job submission command:
podman exec bitnami-spark-master spark-submit --master local[*] \
--jars /opt/spark/extra-jars/mssql-jdbc-12.6.2.jre11.jar,\
/opt/spark/extra-jars/spark-mssql-connector_2.12-1.4.0-BETA.jar \
/opt/spark/scripts/examples/pyspark_mssql_connection.py

Script I am trying to submit
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
if __name__=="__main__":
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MSSQL Connector Example") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Rest of the code

Now the job is correctly running when I use the same shell to submit the job from which I created the image and deployed the container. However when I use a newly connected shell and try to submit the job I am getting an error
Error Snippet:
ERROR StatusLogger Could not reconfigure JMX
java.lang.NullPointerException
....
24/06/07 15:51:10 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:///opt/spark/extra-jars/mssql-jdbc-12.6.2.jre11.jar at spark://fc545e9d0786:35957/jars/mssql-jdbc-12.6.2.jre11.jar with timestamp 1717775469727
24/06/07 15:51:10 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:///opt/spark/extra-jars/spark-mssql-connector_2.12-1.4.0-BETA.jar at spark://fc545e9d0786:35957/jars/spark-mssql-connector_2.12-1.4.0-BETA.jar with timestamp 1717775469727
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/spark/scripts/examples/pyspark_mssql_connection.py", line 18, in <module>
.getOrCreate()
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
....
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException:
.....

Tried things:

Tried to put the script and extra jars inside the container.
.config("spark.driver.bindAddress","localhost")
.config( "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED", )
.config("spark.driver.host", "localhost")

Note: There is no issue in Ubuntu-20.04 when the same image and execution commands are being used.

Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what's less clear is how it ought to be indented. Don't make us guess; please [edit] to fix it. Python syntax crucially depends on correct indentation

The error was due to RedHat 8 which uses kernel version 4.x whereas bitnami/spark:3.4.2 uses latest Debian which uses kernel 6.x. The way it was solved is to downgrade to use debian-10 image for Spark 3.2.1, because this is the last bitnami image which has Debian 10 support. However, debian-10 offers R-3.5.2. However, bitnami/spark:3.2.1 R version is 4.x. So I have to manually install R 4.1.0 to have Spark R work with Debian 10 in RedHat 8.
Dockerfile:
FROM bitnami/spark:3.2.1-debian-10-r121

# Install necessary tools
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -V ca-certificates lsb-release wget gnupg2 build-essential

# Install dependencies for R
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -V \
    gfortran \
    libreadline6-dev \
    libx11-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    xvfb \
    libbz2-dev \
    libzstd-dev \
    liblzma-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    texinfo \
    texlive \
    texlive-fonts-extra \
    screen \
    libpcre2-dev

# Download and install R 4.1.0
WORKDIR /usr/local/src
RUN wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-4/R-4.1.0.tar.gz && \
    tar zxvf R-4.1.0.tar.gz && \
    cd R-4.1.0 && \
    ./configure --enable-R-shlib && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    cd .. && \
    rm -rf R-4.1.0*

# Add Apache Arrow APT repository
RUN wget https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/arrow/debian/apache-arrow-apt-source-latest-buster.deb && \
    apt-get install -y -V ./apache-arrow-apt-source-latest-buster.deb && \
    apt-get update

# Install Apache Arrow libraries and other dependencies
    RUN apt-get install -y -V \
    libarrow-dev \
    libarrow-glib-dev \
    libarrow-dataset-dev \
    libarrow-dataset-glib-dev \
    libarrow-flight-dev \
    libarrow-flight-glib-dev \libgandiva-dev \
libgandiva-glib-dev \
    libparquet-dev \
    libparquet-glib-dev \
    r-cran-dplyr \
    r-cran-tidyr \
    r-cran-devtools \
    python3-pip

# Install PyArrow for Python (make sure it matches the version of Arrow installed)
RUN pip3 install pyarrow numpy pandas matplotlib scikit-learn pyspark==3.2.1

# Install Arrow for R
RUN R -e "install.packages('arrow', repos = 'https://cloud.r-project.org/')"

# Setup environment for SparkR
ENV SPARK_HOME=/opt/bitnami/spark
ENV R_LIBS_USER=${SPARK_HOME}/R/lib
ENV PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
ENV PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3

# Install SparkR
RUN ln -s ${SPARK_HOME}/R/lib/SparkR /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/SparkR
USER 1001

